# gcc error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

Several months ago I ran a `build` file and working without any problem. after that, when I update `Ubuntu 14` and run that again, got some `unexpected errors`:

```
 running build_ext
 building 'allthethings' extension
 /usr/bin/gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch        
 i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC 
 -I/home/xin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include 
 -I/home/xin -I/usr/include 
 -I/home/xin/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -c allthethings.cpp -o 
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/allthethings.o -fopenmp
  gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
  gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
  gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am not sure what is wrong, since the input `source` flag of file, is real simple:

```
export ARCHFLAGS=""
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

The `main` part of the `build_ext` is shown bellow:

```
os.environ["CC"] = "/usr/bin/gcc"
os.environ["CXX"] = "/usr/bin/g++"

from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy
print 'start'
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
"allthethings",                                   # the extesion name
sources=["allthethings.pyx", "channel.cpp", "setupandrun.cpp", 
"file_output.cc", "network.cpp", "levmar.cpp", "mp_mat.cpp",
         "str_double.cpp", "mp_mat_double.cpp", "libcla.c","setup.py"],
libraries=["lapack", "cblas", "fftw3", "m"],
language="c++",
extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'],
extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(),"/home/xin", "/usr/include"]
)))
```

Thanks for anyone help. I'm not sure, but maybe the error is due to recent updates of `ubuntu14`. It is very difficult for me to solve that, since I do not know what the `error message` means.

gcc -v shows:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-  8ubuntu2~14.04' 
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ 
 --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id 
 --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix 
 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls 
 --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes 
 --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib 
 --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre 
 --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 
 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 
 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch 
 --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 
 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
 --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Thread model: posix
      gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04)

Comment: Please show the output of the `gcc -v` command

Comment: The gcc version is: gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04) 4.9.3

Comment: `gcc -v` shows much more information. Including supported architecture(s).

Comment: Run gcc --help and look for the arch flag.

Comment: shouldn't it be `-march`?

Comment: -march does not work. -arch should mean architecture

Comment: How to find arch flag using gcc  --help? I do not see "arch" or "flag" keywords

Comment: @XinZhang : Were you using OS/X previously? `CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"` would be for an OS/X environment which has multiple architecture support for a single executable. _GCC_ on Linux doesn't use `-arch` and will produce errors.  See this [newer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37282524/3857942) I just gave you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281891/gcc-error-i386-no-such-file-or-directory)