# Error trying to build a fat universal binary with gcc on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, architecture, x86-64, i386

I try to run a very simple code, but it reports error, can anyone give some suggestions? I am using Ubuntu14 and gcc4.9.

```
xin@ubuntu:~/pipes$ gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 channel.cpp
gcc: error: i386: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-arch’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use the Apple OS/X (Darwin) GCC/CLang method of compiling code to a universal binary with 2 architectures.

It is different on Linux (including Ubuntu). Linux doesn't have universal binary support for multiple targets in a single executable. It is one architecture per build. Remove `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` and replace it with `-m32` if you are targeting a 32-bit binary, and `-m64` if targeting a 64 bit binary.

32-bit:

```
gcc -m32 channel.cpp
```

64-bit

```
gcc -m64 channel.cpp
```

---

## Special Considerations

You may also have to install the *Multilib* versions of *GCC* (and *G++* if you want to) so that you can properly build and run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Ubuntu using the appropriate *C* libraries. That can be done with this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

On other non-Ubuntu Debian based systems you'd need to use:

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```